# Auto-Login user into Wordpress site displayed in react-native <WebView> from Firebase

Tags: wordpress, firebase, react-native, webview, expo

I have a react-native app running on expo with a login screen on my react-native application. When the user logs in, a JWT token is retrieved from Firebase and passed on to a  which opens up a Wordpress Site. What I am trying to do is to automatically pass this JWT token to the  and log them into the Wordpress site.

I tried several options, like installing the Firebase Authentication plugin by miniOrange, but I didn't know how to make this happen using the free version. I also tried using a custom script using the Code Snippets plugin and entering the below code. I had already installed php-jwt on my root folder in wordpress using compose.

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

add_action('init', 'handle_jwt_token');

function handle_jwt_token() {
  if (!empty($_GET['jwt_token'])) {
    $jwt_token = sanitize_text_field($_GET['jwt_token']);

    // Decode and verify the JWT token
    $jwt_decoded = JWT::decode($jwt_token, YOUR_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID, array('HS256'));

    // Get the user data from the JWT token
    $user_id = $jwt_decoded->sub;
    $user_email = $jwt_decoded->email;
    $user_name = $jwt_decoded->name;

    // Log the user into Wordpress
    $user = get_user_by('email', $user_email);
    if (!$user) {
      // Create a new Wordpress user if they don't already exist
      $user_id = wp_create_user($user_email, wp_generate_password(), $user_email);
      wp_update_user(array(
        'ID' => $user_id,
        'display_name' => $user_name,
      ));
    }

    wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID);
    wp_redirect("https://homepage_url.com");
    exit;
  }
}
```

I just ended up getting an error

> Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/var/www/vhosts/test.com/html/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/admin-menus/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in /var/www/vhosts/test.com/html/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/admin-menus/class-edit-menu.php(253)

My question is, are there any options available for me to achieve this? Thank you for your time in reading this!

Answer (score 0):

You will able to achieve it with this extension.

https://firebase-wordpress-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extensions/jwt.html#remote-authentication-via-url

It will require you generate a token on your React Native and pass it to the WebView, after that WordPress can handle the auto login.

You can try it here: https://dn-wp-autologin.web.app/